# Height Limitation of Winform.cs Coding Page

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2010

There are height limitation of method/eventhandler/construction and global area that is I know but interesting things I want to know about height limitation of winform.cs coding page.

Is there height limitation of winform.cs coding page?. If no then can you describe the design of winform.cs coding page?. Like how it is set/design to unlimited height?.

Comment: Are you asking what the maximum dimentions are of a winform form?

Comment: @rie819, No It's about winform coding page height

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there's no limit to the amount of code you can put behind a page.  Odds are if you're putting a lot of code there though, you aren't writing your code in a way that will promote re-use later.

Comment: @rie819, can you describe it like how it is design to unlimited height.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly, but are you asking how to set the maximum size of your winform?

If so, you can change the MaximumSize property in the designer, or set it yourself in the *.cs file.

Comment: No it's not about winform size it's about winform coding page height

Comment: Can you describe it like how it is design to unlimited height?.

Comment: If I understood your question, then yes, I could answer.

Comment: Mahesh:  The code behind for a form is essentially structured as one text file.  Just like when you write something in notepad, the total height of that file is unlimited, you just get a scroll bar and you continue writing the code.